# Не могу установить PyAudio на Python3.8

Tags: python, pyaudio

Пишет мол не поддерживается платформа 
Пробовал и 32-х разрядную и 64-х
Ничего больше на ум не приходит
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUJCS.png

Comment: Вы пытаетесь установить whl файл для Python2.7 (о чем говорят цифры 27 в его названии) на Python 3.8.

Comment: Да, и вполне возможно, что версия Python 3.8 вообще не поддерживается этой библиотекой (если судить по этой таблице: https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/#files)